# Live text filtering in wordpress Page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filtering, live

I would like to make live text filtering on one page in wordpress.
I try to do it like it is written here:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

but it doesn't works :(

I would like to filter not comments list, but "divs" with the same class in page.

```
<div id="cont">District 1: Street 1, Street 2, Street 3</div>
<div id="cont">District 2: Street 4, Street 5, Street 6</div>
```

And I want that inputting "Street 1" only 1st div would be displayed (to show what district this is).

My code looks like that: 
`<form id="live-search" class="styled" action="" method="post"> <fieldset><input id="filter" class="text-input" type="text" value="" /></fieldset> </form> [call_to_action style="bar" title="Okręg 1" btn_title="Idź do" url="http://url..." target="_self" btn_color="theme"]Filozofów, Oławska, Plac Bramy Wrocławskiej, Prochowa, Wrocławska, Świętej Jadwigi, Długa, Plac Moniuszki, Plac Zamkowy[/call_to_action]`

And i have few call to action boxes that after saving on page become `<div class="call-to-action bar">.`

But when I enters anything the search doesn't work...

Comment: Very nice tutorial, seems so simple. Please, add your code to the question and explain *what* doesn't work. Any error messages?

Comment: My code looks like that:
`<form id="live-search" class="styled" action="" method="post">
<fieldset><input id="filter" class="text-input" type="text" value="" /></fieldset>
</form>
[call_to_action style="bar" title="Okręg 1" btn_title="Idź do" url="http://url..." target="_self" btn_color="theme"]Filozofów, Oławska, Plac Bramy Wrocławskiej, Prochowa, Wrocławska, Świętej Jadwigi, Długa, Plac Moniuszki, Plac Zamkowy[/call_to_action]`

And i have few call to action boxes that after saving on page become `<div class="call-to-action bar">`.

But when I enters anything the search doesn't work...

Comment: You can [edit] the question. It's better to have all your problem written there.